# geom_boxplot not displaying correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-analysis

In the assignment I am doing, it wants me to use geom_boxplot. However, I have been unable to get the graph to display the boxplots correctly.

```
# Convert To Factor
census_data$CIT <- as.factor(census_data$CIT)   
class(census_data$CIT)

ggplot(census_data, aes(census_data[["VALP"]], (census_data[["CIT"]])) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "blue", fill = "orange") +
  ggtitle("Property value by citizenship status") +
  xlab("“Citizenship status") + ylab("Property value")
```

I am slightly concerned that the CIT may not have been converted correctly to a factor. [image]

Comment: You probably want to use `ggplot(census_data, aes(VALP, CIT)) + ....`. But, yes, the real problem lies with the CIT variable. What does that variable actually look like? Can you provide e.g. `dput(head(census_data, 20))` in the question?

Comment: The reproducible example you provided doesn't seem to be close to the real data, moreso the troublesome variable (CIT) is not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have your `x` and `y` aesthetics the wrong way around.  you have `VALP` first which is then assumed to be `x` and `CIT` second which is asssumed to be `y`.  Given your labels I think you want them in the other order.

I always find it helps to label them explicitly, ie `aes(x=.., y=...)` so you don't get confused!

You also don't need to use `census_data[["VALP"]]` in the `aes` function call, since you have supplied the `census_data` in the data argument just saying `aes(x=CIT, y=VALP)` should be enough.